# Does Specflow supports all the supported languages by gherkin?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bdd, specflow

I am new to BDD and Specflow. I am using Specflow on Visual Studio 2013.
Does Specflow supports all the supported languages by gherkin in the following json?
https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/master/gherkin-languages.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes

Long answer: We are supporting the languages, that are supported of the Gherkin Version we are using. Currently this is 4.0.0, so we are supporting the languages in https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin/blob/v4.0.0/gherkin-languages.json

Full disclose: I am one of the maintainers of SpecFlow.

Comment: Then please check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37942289/4609025