# How to use a supported language by gherkin in Specflow?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, bdd, specflow

I want to use persian language for authoring BDD scenarios using Specflow in Visual Studio 2013.
I added following config to specflow config section:

```
<language feature="fa-IR" tool="en" />
```

But when Specflow tries to generate test out of the scenarios, it emits following error:

```
#error The specified feature file language ('fa-IR') is not supported.
```

Comment: Which version of SpecFlow are you using? 1.9, 2.0, 2.1?

Comment: I am using Version 1.9

Comment: I tried the latest version (2.1), but there are other problems in supporting 'fa-IR' language. I've posted an issue for this:  https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/651